# Newtonsoft.json.dll being copied in build server

Tags: c#, tfs, build, reference, blend

I am trying to build a WCF C# project,which is not using the Newtonsoft.Json.dll.
I checked the packages.config and *.csproj files.

When building the app in build server, Newtonsoft.Json.dll is copied to bin path
Build log:
Copying file from "d:\Microsoft Visual stdio 12.0\blend\newtonsoft.json.dll" to "\\bin\newtonsoft.json.dll"

Why it is getting copied ?

Comment: Perhaps you're referring to something that refers to it?

Comment: You may be using other libraries which have dependencies on Newtonsoft

Comment: What kind of project is it?

Comment: check the references

Comment: You may referenced Newtonsoft directly or indirectly, just check your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the guys said above, you may be using other libraries which have dependencies on Newtonsoft. So, just check your project.

Here is a reference for you:

> When `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll`(or
>   `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll`) referenced by the TFS
>   plugin is set to `CopyLocal`(or `Private`), the builder will copy all
>   its dependencies to the plugins folder, such as
>
> - `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Diff.dll`
> - `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll`
> - `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll`
> - `Newtonsoft.Json.dll version 4.5.0`
>
> **Source link** :
>   https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3041